# How to check if a table exists and return a value (0/1) if it doesn't without using a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've only been able to see this work with a stored procedure and I can't figure out the syntax.  I basically have some external system calling a SQL query and I want to verify the table exists first using code similar to this:

```
if (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND  TABLE_NAME = 'OrderUpdates'))
  BEGIN
    --return 1 or 0 if it exists or doesn't exist
  END
```

I can't get the return statement to work properly.

Comment: return is only for stored procedures.

Comment: Do you mean return or select?

Comment: I meant that I wanted a result set of one row with one value in one column.  Not sure the correct verbiage to explain that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS BIT) -- Should be unique to give 0 or 1 as result
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'OrderUpdates'
    -- Not sure if you want views or not:
    AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand quite what you are getting at - RETURN is only valid in a stored procedure or function.

If you want the same thing in a set (because the caller is expecting a rowset), then something like this can work:

```
SELECT 1 AS DoesItExist
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'OrderUpdates'
UNION ALL
SELECT 0
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'OrderUpdates')
```

Comment: I put the return in a comment because I wasn't sure the correct word to use.  I wanted it to return a value.

Comment: @Alex K Return can return a table from a table-valued function, but generally can only return a single value.  A procedure which selects various things will return result sets as well as a return value (and you also have the option of output parameters), but the result sets are not really return values.  It sounded like you didn't want to use a stored procedure, so I wasn't sure what you were returning anything to.  I figured that meant you could only have SQL which produced result sets which the client could then be configured to interpret (i.e. one value in a row).

Comment: Yes exactly, a single result set is what I was going for.  I think this works too

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has a table named 'tables', which contains the list of tables in your database.  So following code should help:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DoesTableExist(@table VARCHAR(50), @exists BIT OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = @table)
    SET @exists = 1
ELSE
    SET @exists = 0

RETURN @exists
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
USE SomeDatabase;
IF OBJECT_ID('YourTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    SELECT 1
END ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT 0
END
```

If you're looking for a type other than a User Table, you can change the 'U' in `OBJECT_ID` to the correct value as determined by the types listed in [`sys.objects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx)

Comment: This could easily give false positives because of objects other than tables (or views).

Comment: @TimLehner You caught me in between edits. :-) See the revised answer!